# Can't connect Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 after Windows 10 update?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2, windows-10

I have a domain joined HyperV Server Core 2012 R2 machine, and a domain joined service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within workstation which was in-place upgraded from Windows Pro 8.1 to Windows 10 Pro.  Prior to the update I was able to use Hyper-V Manager to connect to the 2012 R2 server to manage the VMs on that machine.  After the update I get this error:

```
[Window Title]
Hyper-V Manager

[Main Instruction]
An error occurred while attempting to connect to server "HYPERV01". Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server.

[Content]
The operation on computer 'HYPERV01' failed: WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM the same local subnet.

[Close]
```

The workstation and server are on the same subnet, and I checked that Remote Management and some other Hyper-V exceptions are enabled in the firewall.  How to I correct this?

EDIT:  I'm not sure anymore if the Win10 update had anything to do with it.  By entering the first command on the accepted answer **on the hyperv server**, i was able to connect again via the Hyper-V manager in Windows 10 with no other changes (not even the `winrm set` command was needed).  So it could be that a recent Windows Update on the server reset the firewall rules, as `enter-psssession hyperv01` was also failing, I later discovered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to enable the use of WinRM to connect to your Hyper-V server.  To do this you will need to:

Open the Start menu
Click on All Programs and then on Accessories
Right click on Command Prompt and select Run as administrator
Type in `winrm quickconfig` and hit enter.  You will then need to say ‘y’ (yes) to a couple of prompts

Type in: `winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputerName"}'`    and hit enter. Substitute "RemoteComputerName" with the name or IP address of your Hyper-V server.

After the Windows 10 upgrade you have to re-authorize the Hyper-V server again.
That's it.. resolved.

the command line entry was missing the single quotes around @{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputerName"}. it needs to be `'@{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputerName"}'`

Comment: Are these companiesmmands on the client or server?  Why did i not have to do this originally?

Comment: Ok, I have no idea why (maybe a recent Windows update on the server), but runing `winrm quickconfig` prompted me to allow firewall exceptions after saying they were not, and answering Y fixed this.  So perhaps this had nothing to do with my updating to Win10 and had to do with the last batch of updates.  The `winrm set` command for me was not needed at all. I decided to try this after I discoverd that `enter-pssession hyperv01` was also failing, where it had been working previously.

Comment: I had the same issue with non-domain situation, the command: winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputerName"} resolved my issue, but each time I reboot the Win 10 client, I need to retype it again to make connection to the remote host, any idea ?

Comment: Does not work, it reports back "Error: Invalid use of command line."

Answer (score 0):

I updated to windows 10 as well and suffered the same issue, When I read your post it occurred to me I wasn't logged onto the domain. Windows 10 reverted back to a local user account for sign-in.

Once I logged in on the domain my issue was resolved, I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry but that's not my issue.